# How can I insert a large amount of files in a MS Word docx efficiently?

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm trying to insert a large amount of images on a MS Word document using python docx library, but it is too slow. I have around 900 images.

My procedure to do this is create a dictionary with a label and the location of the image. Then I create a table (2 columns) with the labels to positionate the images and with a function I defined, I replace the labels with the images.

```py
import docx
import os

document = docx.Document("./" + template)
def insert_image2(image_path, image_label, document, image_inches = 3):
    ###
    #we insert the image path and the image label on the text. The function replaces the label on the text by the image.
    #one example for a label could be image_label = "[image]""
    ###
    from docx import Document
    from docx.shared import Inches


    for table in document.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    if image_label in paragraph.text:
                        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.strip().replace(image_label, "")

                        run = paragraph.add_run()
                        run.add_picture(image_path, width=Inches(image_inches))


    return

polar_values = os.listdir("./plots/polar")
l_fil = [x for x in polar_values if "foundation" not in x]
polar_keys = [i.split("WT", 1)[1].split(".png")[0].strip() for i in l_fil]

polar_dict = dict(zip(polar_keys,polar_values))

even = polar_keys[1:][::2] #even indexed numbers
odd = polar_keys[::2] #odd indexed numbers

#Adding table
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=2)
for ind in range(len(odd)):
    row = table.add_row().cells
    row[0].add_paragraph(odd[ind])
    row[1].add_paragraph(even[ind])


for key, value in polar_dict.items():
    insert_image2("./plots/polar/" + value, key, document)


document.save(out_file)
```

**EDIT**
I have decided to append the image to the bottom of the document with the command "run.add_picture(image_path)".

Comment: I expect the time is going into repeated traversal of the table and cells. Those calculations are a bit time-consuming because of the need to account for merged cells (even when none are present). Try reorganizing your code so you only traverse the table once, perhaps doing that work right when you add a new row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you over-engineered this thing.  If you want to insert a bunch of images into a Word document, just use VBA for the task.

Either...select folder with images...

```
Sub InsertImages()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim mg1 As Range
    Dim mg2 As Range

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    With fd
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg", 1
        .FilterIndex = 1

        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vItem In .SelectedItems
                Set mg2 = ActiveDocument.Range
                mg2.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
                  FileName:=vItem, _
                  LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=mg2
                Set mg1 = ActiveDocument.Range
                mg1.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

                mg1.Text = vbCrLF & vbCrLf
            Next vItem
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Or...don't select folder; map straight to it...

```
Sub GetPictures()
    Dim sPic As String
    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = "c:\myfolder\"
    sPic = Dir(sPath & "*.jpg")

    Do While sPic <> ""
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
          FileName:=sPath & sPic, _
          LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        sPic = Dir
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.TypeParagraph
    Loop
End Sub
```

Post back if you have additional questions related to this.  If you want to do something quite different, post a different question.